# AngularJS ng-repeat doesn't work

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am new to AngularJS and in a learning stage.
I am trying to use ng-repeat,have the controller in a separate js file.
When i run ,nothing displays. Its is just blank

**index.html**:

```
<html data-ng-app="">
    <head>
        <script src="/Scripts/angular.js"></script>
        <script src="/controllers/controller.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body data-ng-contoller='CartController'>
        <div data-ng-repeat="item in Items">
            <span>{{item.Name}}</span>
            <span>{{item.Buyer}}</span>
            <input type="text" data-ng-model="item.Quantity" />
            <span>{{item.Price}}</span>
            <span>Total Price</span>{{item.Quantity * item.Price | currency}}
            <button data-ng-click="remove($index)">Remove</button>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

controller.js:

```
function CartController($scope) {
$scope.Items=
   [{ Name: "Books", Quantity:12,Price : 20, Buyer: "Wei-Meng Lee" },
    { Name: "Pencils", Quantity: 17, Price : 35, Buyer: "Scott Allen" },
    { Name: "Markers", Quantity: 2, Price: 30, Buyer: "Adam Fazio" }];

$scope.remove = function(index) {
    $scope.Items.splice(index, 1);
};

$scope.$apply();
```

}

Comment: Remove scope.apply in your controller it is no needed

Comment: When i click Remove button , nothing really happens.

Comment: $scope.Items.remove... remove is not an array method. What you are looking for is splice function
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice

Comment: $scope.Items.splice(index, 1);

Comment: I am afraid that this isn't working, does we need to mentiion anything else, since each item as collections of objects

Comment: i was able to make it, it should be remove($index)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is typo `data-ng-contoller` instead of `data-ng-controller`. The correct will be:

```
<body data-ng-controller='CartController'>
```

Comment: oh...such a silly mistake..Thanks Dalorzo for the quick response!